# VB.NET & SQL : The ConnectionString property has not been initialized

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

I'm trying to create a search, where the SQL query depends on a radio button and a textbox. The table, textbox and radio button are all on the same form. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 for Web, and trying to change the data source for a GridView object on the form. However, I keep getting the error:

***The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.***

How can I fix this?
Below is my full code.

```
Protected Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim sqlQuery As String = ""
    If radClient.Checked = True Then
        GridView1.Visible = False
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ClientID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radItem.Checked = True Then
        GridView1.Visible = False
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE ItemID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = True Then
        GridView1.Visible = False
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE UserID = '" & txtSearch.Text & "'"
    ElseIf radUser.Checked = False And radClient.Checked = False And radItem.Checked = False Then
        ErrorLabel.Text = "Error: You have not chosen a search criteria."
        Return
    End If
    SqlDataSource3.SelectCommand = sqlQuery
    SqlDataSource3.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Credits to @Steve, @MuhammadOmar, @Westie and @AmitApollo for help with the code in my previous thread.

Thank you!

Comment: First things first, please use SQL Parameters.

Comment: I will once I'm done, but I'm just trying to get it to work now :)

Comment: Also, this is a local application for my own server, and no one has access to it except me, and it's protected by a login using parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks if anyone actually was able to hold my system.

Comment: set ConnectionString property of SqlDataSource before DataBind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do it like

make a global connection variable

```
dim con as new SQLConnection
con.connectionsting = "Set your connection string"
con.open
```

after when you write what your code then write

```
con.close
```

it will solve your problem

help it helps.